# Flutter Local JSON Update

Tags: android, json, flutter

```
{
"id" : 0,
"series": "Peaky Blinders",
"episode": "S2 - B6",
"youtubeUrl": "link",
"accent": "british",
"fav" : false,
"watched" : false
}
```

Hello, I have a local JSON file that finds the data like this. I want to make the "fav" value the opposite of the current value when a button is clicked. What should I do for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myVar = {
"id" : 0,
"series": "Peaky Blinders",
"episode": "S2 - B6",
"youtubeUrl": "link",
"accent": "british",
"fav" : false,
"watched" : false
};

myVar['fav'] = !myVar['fav'];
```

Comment: but this happens for a variable. I need to read the json file first, then update it, then save it.